# Mathematical formulas as objects in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement propositional logic in c++. Two issues, the first one is I am having issues with creating the implication and if and only if operators. The second issue I have is implementing the assignment class. An assignment should be an object that given a formula determines whether it is true under that assignment. The thing is the connectors are implemented as a class and then I overload the operator inside formula. I would like to make the connector class into an operator that works on formulas. Also I am not sure if there is a solution to for this but I would like to not have to use pointers everywhere to avoid slicing variables into formulas. Any help is appreciated.

```
// History
// Created: Oscar Grove 28/12/2021
//
// Modified: Oscar Grove 30/12/2021
//           Oscar Grove 22/05/2023

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class connective
{
    int val;

public:
    connective ()
    {
    }

    ~connective ()
    {
    }

    connective (int x)
    {
        val = x;
    }

    int value ()
    {
        return val;
    }

    void assign (int x)
    {
        val = x;
    }

    string label ()
    {
        if (val == -1)
            return "¬";

        if (val == 0)
            return "";

        if (val == 1)
            return u8"\u2227";

        if (val == 2)
            return u8"\u2228";

        if (val == 3)
            return "->";

        else
            return "<->";
    }
};

class formula
{
    connective con;

    formula *f, *g;

public:
    formula ()
    {
    }

    ~formula ()
    {
    }

    formula (int n, formula* p, formula* q)
    {
        con.assign (n);

        f = p;
        g = q;
    }

    formula (int n, formula* p)
    {
        con.assign (n);

        f = p;
    }

    virtual void print ()
    {
        if (con.value () == -1)
        {
            cout << con.label();
            f -> print ();
        }

        else
        {
            cout << "(";

            f -> print ();

            cout << " " << con.label () << " ";

            g -> print ();

            cout << ")"; 
        }
    }

    virtual char type ()
    {
        return 'F';
    }

    formula operator and (formula* x)
    {
        return formula (1, this, x);
    }

    formula operator or (formula* x)
    {
        return formula (2, this, x);
    }

    formula* left ()
    {
        return f;
    }

    formula* right ()
    {
        return g;
    }

    formula operator not ()
    {
        return formula (-1, this);
    }
    
    /*formula operator >> (formula* x)
    {
        return formula (3, this x);
    }

    formula operator <> (formula* x)
    {
        return formula (4, this, x);
    }*/
};

class variable: public formula
{
    char symbol;

public:
    variable () : formula ()
    {
    }

    ~variable ()
    {
    }

    variable (char c) : formula ()
    {
        symbol = c;
    }

    char label ()
    {
        return symbol;
    }

    void print ()
    {
        cout << symbol;
    }

    char type ()
    {
        return 'C';
    }

    bool operator == (variable x)
    {
        return x.label () == symbol;
    }
};
```

```
// History
// Created: Oscar Grove 30/12/2021
//
// Modified: Oscar Grove 22/05/2023

#include "formula.h"

using namespace std;

class set
{
    set *node, *left, *right;   


    void add (variable x)
    {

    }

    void remove (variable x)
    {

    }
    
public:
    set ()
    {
    }

    ~set ()
    {
    }

    bool contains (set* s)
    {
        if (node == NULL)
            return false;

        if (*s == *node)
            return true;

        return left -> contains (s) or right -> contains (s);
    }

    /*set operator + (set* a, set* b)
    {

    }

    set operator - (set* a, set* b)
    {

    }

    set union ()
    {
    }*/
};

class assignment
{
    set S;

    bool applied (formula* F)
    {
        if (F -> type () == 'C')
            return 1;

        return applied (F -> left ())
    }
}
```

```
// History
// Created: Oscar Grove 30/12/2021
//
// Modified: Oscar Grove 22/05/2023

#include "formula.h"

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    variable a ('A'), b ('B'), c ('C'), d ('D');

    formula F = a and &b, G = not c, X (3, &F, &G);

    G.left () -> type ();

    X.print ();

    cout << endl;
}
```

I am aware set is not yet implemented but it is not relevant to my question.

I tried creating a constructor for a formula pointer but that did not work out. Regarding the assignment class I could try and do a switch to go case by case but my objective would be to be able to write expressions as mathematically as possible so that the functioning of an object is as close as possible to the definition of the mathematical object.

Comment: `formula () { }` -- `~set () {} ` -- You should initialize all of your member variables, and not leave them uninitialized.  Also using names like `set` may get confusing if you ever need to use `std::set`.

Comment: Those are just the empty constructor and destructor functions. Also I the idea is to create my own set I won’t be using std::set

Comment: I know they are empty constructors -- that's the issue.  `formula f; formuala* f2 = f.left();` -- That is what your current code is vulnerable to.  What if `f2` is used, knowing it is uninitialized?

Comment: *I won’t be using std::set*  -- Since this is supposed to be a class, you don't know what the user of the class will be doing.  Never write code assuming *you* won't do something -- I csould easily do `#include <set>` and use your library, then everything falls apart since you have `set` somewhere as a variable name in your header file.

Comment: Also see this [stack exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/11154/propositional-logic-proposition-evaluator) post as to propositional logic and C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written several small languages like this (although not Propositional Logic in particular) and have come up with a somewhat standard starting design that uses a `std::variant` to store the different types and relies on `std::shared_ptr` (although you could also use `std::unique_ptr` if you do not intend to group common sub-expressions) for the connectivity when building expressions.

You mentioned not wanting to use pointers, but I think it is the best option for representing expressions that are built and manipulated at runtime. This is especially true if you want to do optimizations and other transformations on the expression. From the usage perspective, using `std::shared_ptr` is as clean as using objects.

I sketched out some code and here is a usage example:

### Usage

```cpp
using std::cout, std::endl;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    auto f = !(ptrue() || "A"_v);
    auto g = simplify(f);
    cout << f << endl;
    cout << g << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```cpp
¬ (⊤ ∨ A)
⊥
```

If this is something you'd like to work on as a small open source project, I would be interesting in helping out.

### Code

```cpp
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>

// Pattern match a `std::variant` derived type against its contained type.
//
// match helpers
namespace detail {
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;
}; // detail

template<class T, class... Us>
auto match(T&& variant, Us&&... handlers) {
    return std::visit(detail::overloaded{std::forward<Us>(handlers)...}, std::forward<T>(variant));
}

// Logic symobls using unicode.
namespace uch {
inline constexpr auto True = "\u22a4";
inline constexpr auto False = "\u22a5";
inline constexpr auto Negation = "\u00ac";
inline constexpr auto Conjunction = "\u2227";
inline constexpr auto Disjunction = "\u2228";
inline constexpr auto Implies = "\u2192";
inline constexpr auto Equivalence = "\u2194";
};

// Declare the Proposition types.
struct Variable;
struct True;
struct False;
struct Negation;
struct Conjunction;
struct Disjunction;
struct Implies;
struct Equivalence;

// The variant type that holds a Proposition.
using Base = std::variant<
    Variable,
    True,
    False,
    Negation,
    Conjunction,
    Disjunction,
    Implies,
    Equivalence
    >;

// All Proposition's are shared pointers.
using Proposition = std::shared_ptr<Base>;

// Define the Proposition types.
struct Variable {
    Variable(const std::string& v) : name(v) { }
    std::string name;
};

struct True { };

struct False { };

struct Negation {
    Negation(Proposition p) : child(p) { }
    Proposition child;
};

struct Conjunction {
    Conjunction(Proposition p, Proposition q) : left(p), right(q) { }
    Proposition left, right;
};

struct Disjunction {
    Disjunction(Proposition p, Proposition q) : left(p), right(q) { }
    Proposition left, right;
};
struct Implies {
    Implies(Proposition p, Proposition q) : left(p), right(q) { }
    Proposition left, right;
};

struct Equivalence {
    Equivalence(Proposition p, Proposition q) : left(p), right(q) { }
    Proposition left, right;
};

// Helpers for creating Propositions.
template<class T, class... Args>
Proposition proposition(Args... args) {
    return std::make_shared<Base>(T{args...});
}

Proposition variable(const std::string& v) {
    return proposition<Variable>(v);
}

Proposition ptrue() {
    return proposition<True>();
}

Proposition pfalse() {
    return proposition<False>();
}

Proposition negation(Proposition child) {
    return proposition<Negation>(child);
}

Proposition conjunction(Proposition l, Proposition r) {
    return proposition<Conjunction>(l, r);
}

Proposition disjunction(Proposition l, Proposition r) {
    return proposition<Disjunction>(l, r);
}

Proposition implies(Proposition l, Proposition r) {
    return proposition<Implies>(l, r);
}

Proposition equivalence(Proposition l, Proposition r) {
    return proposition<Equivalence>(l, r);
}

// Variable literals.
Proposition operator ""_v(const char *s, size_t) {
    std::string str(s);
    return variable(str);
}

// Use the builtin operators to construct Propositions.
auto operator!(Proposition p) {
    return negation(p);
}

auto operator&&(Proposition p, Proposition q) {
    return conjunction(p, q);
}

auto operator||(Proposition p, Proposition q) {
    return disjunction(p, q);
}

auto operator==(Proposition p, Proposition q) {
    return equivalence(p, q);
}

// Output a Proposition
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Proposition p) {
    match
        (*p,
         [&](const Variable& v) {
             os << v.name;
         },
         [&](const True&) {
             os << uch::True;
         },
         [&](const False&) {
             os << uch::False;
         },
         [&](const Negation& p) {
             os << uch::Negation << " " << p.child;
         },
         [&](const Conjunction& p) {
             os << "(" << p.left << " " << uch::Conjunction << " " << p.right << ")";
         },
         [&](const Disjunction& p) {
             os << "(" << p.left << " " << uch::Disjunction << " " << p.right << ")";
         },
         [&](const Implies& p) {
             os << "(" << p.left << " " << uch::Implies << " " << p.right << ")";
         },
         [&](const Equivalence& p) {
             os << "(" << p.left << " " << uch::Equivalence << " " << p.right << ")";
         },
         [&](const auto&) {
             os << "???";
         }
         );
    return os;
}

// Simplification
Proposition simplify_not(Proposition child) {
    return match
        (*child,
         [](const True& f) { return pfalse(); },
         [](const False& f) { return ptrue(); },
         [&](const Negation& f) { return f.child; },
         [&](const auto&) { return negation(child); }
         );
}

Proposition simplify_and(Proposition left, Proposition right) {
    if (std::holds_alternative<False>(*left) or std::holds_alternative<False>(*right))
        return pfalse();
    else if (std::holds_alternative<True>(*left) and std::holds_alternative<True>(*right))
        return ptrue();
    else
        return conjunction(left, right);
}

Proposition simplify_or(Proposition left, Proposition right) {
    if (std::holds_alternative<False>(*left) and std::holds_alternative<False>(*right))
        return pfalse();
    else if (std::holds_alternative<True>(*left) or std::holds_alternative<True>(*right))
        return ptrue();
    else
        return disjunction(left, right);
}

Proposition simplify(Proposition node) {
    return match
        (*node,
         [&](const Negation& f) {  return simplify_not(simplify(f.child)); },
         [&](const Conjunction& f) { return simplify_and(simplify(f.left), simplify(f.right)); },
         [&](const Disjunction& f) { return simplify_or(simplify(f.left), simplify(f.right)); },
         [&](const auto&) { return node; }
         );
}
```

Comment: That is very helpful thanks. I like the idea of using variant but I must admit I do not fully understand your code. I have updated my code to better reflect propositional logic and to be able to generalize, here is the github page https://github.com/oscargrove/Logic. Any help is more than welcome :)

Comment: If you give me your github I can add you as a collaborator.